# MPU6050 Python Library

Tags: python, hardware, mpu6050

I would like to use my MPU6050 gyro/accelerometer in some projects but I can't find a good library. I would prefer it to be in python but can deal with C++. I want something where I can do a simple detection of the gyro. I don't want extreme precision. Is there a library out there that would suffice? I tried [this CPP code](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/download/file.php?id=1575) using the demo_raw binary and it gave these results on a level surface with no movement or vibration:

```
MPU6050 connection successful
a/g:  32767   -424  16284     -335   -143     35

a/g:  32767   -320  16408     -351   -142     33

a/g:  32767   -380  16440     -357   -129     25

a/g:  32767   -328  16340     -370   -104     32

a/g:  32767   -336  16436     -341   -128     49

a/g:  32767   -332  16256     -320   -105     22

a/g:  32767   -252  16292     -358   -117     23

a/g:  32767   -328  16368     -360   -130     48

a/g:  32767   -416  16112     -357   -116     29

a/g:  32767   -432  16336     -354   -120     37

a/g:  32767   -356  16428     -349   -126     23

a/g:  32767   -292  16220     -357   -129     27

a/g:  32767   -376  16420     -357   -101     28

a/g:  32767   -384  16220     -360   -124     32

a/g:  32767   -384  16268     -371   -135     12

a/g:  32767   -328  16256     -350   -126     31

a/g:  32767   -276  16392     -383   -109     31

a/g:  32767   -476  16520     -341   -112     35
```

I am mainly concerned with the last three columns that are x, y, and z of the gyro. Why would there be such difference in the readings when I am not even touching it? If there is an explanation I can use this library. Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This snippet will provide angle after manipulating the values from MPU-6050
[MPU-6050-kalman-filter-python](https://github.com/rocheparadox/Kalman-Filter-Python-for-mpu6050) .

Reading gyroscope and accelerometer values from MPU-6050 is just reading the data from an address of the module. But to fetch some useful information from the same requires some noise filtering and data-fusion algorithm. The above module or snippet will help you achieve the same using a data-fusion algorithm called Kalman filter.

P.S - This algorithm was used in Apollo Guidance Computer that helped NASA put man on the moon :)

Answer (score 0):

There is this library. https://github.com/Tijndagamer/mpu6050 I haven't tried it but it looks to be what you want.